# Python Regular Expressions to match option of strings

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python and Python RE.

I am trying to make a parser for ARM assembly code. I want to make regular expression for matching conditional branch instructions which could be:

```
beq, bne, blt, bgt
```

I tried a regular expression of the form

```
'b[eq|ne|lt|gt]'
```

But this does not match. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: [works on my machine](http://ideone.com/RhpAHr).

Comment: @Kevin If you print the match, you will see that only `be` matched :) Otherwise, strictly speaking, yes, it matches.

Comment: Ok, revision: "doesn't work on my machine, but exhibits a different failure mode than what you reported". I get a match that isn't quite correct; the OP gets no match at all.

Answer (score 7):

You should be using parentheses for options, not square brackets:

```
b(eq|ne|lt|gt)
```

And you'd usually want a non-capture group:

```
b(?:eq|ne|lt|gt)
```

And you can also make it a little more optimised too:

```
b(?:eq|ne|[lg]t)
```

---

Square brackets will be understood as being any of the characters or range of characters. So `[eq|ne|lt|gt]` effectively means either one of `e`, `q`, `|`, `n`, `e` (again, so it becomes redundant), etc.

Comment: What's the significance of a non-capturing group?

Comment: @bozdoz: you probably don't want to capture, say "eq" as a group.

Comment: @bozdoz A capture group will eat a little chunk of your virtual memory (because it stores the capture), while a non-capture group won't. It then goes like 'Do you want it to eat unnecessary virtual memory?' :)

Comment: @user1622490 It is making a group all right, and you need a group here. `[ ... ]` is a character class.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following pattern: `b(?:eq|ne|lt|gt)`

- `[]` **Character set**: Will only match any one character inside the brackets. You can specify a range of characters by using the metacharacter `-`, eg: `[a-e]` or even negate the expression by using the metacharacter `^`, eg: `[^aeiou]`
- `()` **Capturing parentesis**: Used for grouping part & for creating number capturing group, you can disable this feature by using the following char-set `?:` within the capturing parentesis, eg`(?:)`

As mentioned above, you should be using the `capturing parentesis` for more than one character  to be matched, so, that is why your pattern using `brackets` did not match your string.

Please note that using the `non capturing parentesis` was meant to no save any data being matched, however you can remove the metacharacters `?:` in order to capture the group.

As python performs perl compatible regular expression engine, you are able to use `named captured groups & numbered backreferences`, the main advantage of using it, is to keep your expression easy to maintain, read, edit, etc.

Eg:

- `(?P<opcode>b(?:eq|ne|lt|gt))` - Will capture the match of your pattern `b(?:eq|ne|lt|gt)` into the backreference name `opcode`